# Prevent intent from being started

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is there a way to prevent an intent from being started?

I'm working with a buggy third-party component that launches 2 similar intents in a row. This causes my app to display two activities, one on top of the other, and the user has to press back twice to return to the original activity.

I was wondering if I could circumvent this behaviour somehow. Is there some kind of intent listener where I can cancel the extra intent before actually being started?

More context:

- It's an ACTION_SEND intent.
- I can't modify the manifest of the activity it calls.
- I can modify the source cody of the activity that will be paused.
- I have access to both intents but I can only modify the first one. The second one I would like to cancel.